# What spectrum of light does penetrate fog?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I am wondering about what spectrum of light does penetrate fog the best. I would like to know if IR light penetrate fog better than UV light and why is that. Thank you for answers.

Comment: A good guide is that the scattering intensity is $\sim 1/\lambda^4$, ($\lambda$ is wavelength) but there are different regimes depending in the size of the scattering particles vs the wavelength. On this basis ir has lower scattering than UV.

Comment: And continuing to longer wavelengths, there is terahertz radiation, for body scanning in airports, etc., and, of course, radar! Without radar, we would know very little of the surface of Venus, which, to put it mildly, is heavily fogged in!

Comment: This is more of a physics question than a chemistry one. So, you should try physics.SE.